# Selenium IDE: How to select from a variable?

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I'm trying to select an option from a variable.

These don't work:

```
select | name=UserID | label=${varUserID} 

select | name=UserID | label=javascript{storedVars['varUserID']}
```

I keep getting:

```
Option with label '${varUserID}' not found

Option with label 'javascript{storedVars['varUserID']}' not found
```

What am I missing?

Sure here is the html:

```
<label for="UN">User Name </label>
<select id="UN" name="UserID" style="width:250px;">
    <option value="12345">LastName, FirstName</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Can you provide the `html` please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You do not have the variable set. If your variable was set you'd see this error message: [error] Option with label 'x' not found

and not Option with label '${varUserID}' not found

And your second example (with javascript) I think isn't working because you're trying to combine test with javascript, this would work: javascript{'label='+storedVars['variable']}

Answer (score 0):

From what you've posted there it's failing because the label isn't the user Id which you've stored, the HTML suggests that the label is the name

```
<option value="12345">LastName, FirstName</option>
```